# CSS order property doesn't work in my project

Tags: html, css

I am learning ccs, js, html and I tried to make a fun little game in which a button runs away from you when you try to click in using the "order: " property but for some reason it doesn't work properly

My html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Click me</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel = "stylesheet" href="../Annyoing click me app/index.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>Don't click me</div>
        <div>Don't click me</div>
        <div id = "click-me">Click me</div>
        <div>Don't click me</div>
        <div>Don't click me</div>

        <script src = "../Annyoing click me app/index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

My CSS

```
html, body {height: 100%; overflow: hidden;}

body {
    background-color: black;

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

div {
    width: 15%;
    height: 80px;
    margin: 20px;

    background-color: red;
    border: 6px solid darkred;

    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

    font-size: 40px;
}

#click-me {
    background-color: green;
    border: 6px solid darkgreen;
    order: 4;
}
```

for some reason the green button always appears at the end of the row

Comment: Please add the full working code along with js so that it can be debugged by contributors. If that's not possible, share a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also to share full working code, you can use the inbuilt code playground provided by Stack Overflow.

Comment: can you share the JS code as well? Are you binding any event for the click-me button? If yes, what is the event handler implementation? Also, for your case `display: flex` should be added only on the body (container for all the divs) for the order property to be effective

Comment: all flex-children have `order: 0` by default. if you want to have the `#click-me`-element as the first element, you can use `order: -1`, that way it will always be the first element. otherwise, you're gonna have to specify `order` on the other elements as well.

Comment: Thanks you @SigurdMazanti it looks like this fixed the issue. Could you please add an answer to the post so I can mark it as accepted?

Comment: Incidentally, to avoid annoying problems with spaces in URLs, you might want to omit the spaces. E.g.: "../AnnoyingClickMeApp/index.js" - and avoiding typos and incorrect spellings will help keep you sane for now ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All `flex`-children have `order: 0` by default. If you want to have the `#click-me`-element as the first element, you can use `order: -1`, that way it will always be the first element. If you want it to work dynamically, you're gonna have to specify `order` on the other elements as well.

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

div {
  width: 15%;
  height: 80px;
  margin: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  border: 6px solid darkred;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 40px;
}

#click-me {
  background-color: green;
  border: 6px solid darkgreen;
  /* Always the first item */
  /*order: -1;*/
  order: 4;
}

div:first-of-type {
  order: 1;
}

div:nth-of-type(2) {
  order: 2;
}

div:nth-of-type(4) {
  order: 4;
}

div:nth-of-type(5) {
  order: 3;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>Don't click me</div>
  <div>Don't click me</div>
  <div id="click-me">Click me</div>
  <div>Don't click me</div>
  <div>Don't click me</div>
</body>
```